# WSL(Ubuntu 18.04)にMeCabをインストールできない

Tags: ubuntu, mecab, wsl

64bit版Windows10にWindows Subsystem for LinuxとUbuntu 18.04を導入して、MeCabとIPA辞書をインストールしようとしましたが、IPAの辞書インストール途中にエラーが出てうまくいきませんでした。

http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#install-unix

行った手順としては、mecab-0.996.tar.gzとmecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gzをコピーして、サイトの手順通りに進めました。

```
 $ tar zxfv mecab-0.996.tar.gz
 $ cd mecab-X.X
 $ ./configure 
 $ make
 $ make check
 $ sudo make install
```

mecabはインストールできました。

```
$ tar zxfv mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz
$ cd mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for mecab-config... /usr/local/bin/mecab-config
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
$ make
/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d . -o . -f EUC-JP -t euc-jp
/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index: error while loading shared 
libraries: libmecab.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:253: recipe for target 'matrix.bin' failed
make: *** [matrix.bin] Error 127
```

IPA辞書がインストールできませんでした。

aclocalとautomakeはautotools-devを使えばいいとaskUbuntuに書いてありましたが、apt-getで配布しているバージョンが新しすぎてapt-getだけではうまくいかないように思いました。私はLinuxアプリケーションのビルドに詳しくないのでここで詰まった感じです。

https://askubuntu.com/questions/45480/how-do-i-install-aclocal

解決法が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示のほどをよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません。MeCabの公式サイトの方法だと環境変数や文字コード等の設定が必要になり、難しいと判断したので「WSL mecab」で検索しました。そのときに見つけた記事がこちらになります。

[NEologd 辞書 を Windows 用 MeCab に導入して Python で使う方法](https://qiita.com/ChenZheChina/items/42f1fcc763e88cb02cca)

ただ、上記の記事の中に、下記記事の紹介がありました。

[ubuntu 18.04 に mecab をインストール](https://qiita.com/ekzemplaro/items/c98c7f6698f130b55d53)

そのような経緯で、MeCabをソースコードからビルドするのではなくUbuntuのディストリビューションで配布されているバイナリを使うこととしました。この方法だと、環境変数やその他設定ファイルなどを設定しなくともインストールすることができます。

Comment: 「ソースコードからのインストールではなく、ディストリビューション提供のパッケージをインストールした」ということが分かるように書いてあるとより親切かなと思います。 / 前者は`/usr/local`以下にインストールされるので`PATH`や`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`の設定を調整する必要がありますが、後者の場合はそれらをあまり意識する必要がない、という違いがあります。

Comment: cubickさん、ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答を修正いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

mecab 本体を `make install` した際に、以下のようなメッセージが出ているはずです。

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
```

この注意書きの通りで、要するに mecab のライブラリである libmecab.so.2 がどこにあるのかソフトウェア側に教えてあげていないので見つからず、エラーになっています。

デフォルトではライブラリは `/usr/local/lib` 下にインストールされるので、このパスを `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` に追加してあげると辞書の `make` も通るはずです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。LD_LIBRARY_PATHを設定して、かつ、sudo apt-get upgradeをかけるとIPA辞書のインストールまでできるようになりました。ただ、mecabを実行するとmecabのインストールに書いてある通りの動作にならず、多分LD_RUN_PATHも設定が必要なのだと思います。もう少しやってみます。